# Saving settings in matlab

Tags: preferences, matlab

A dumb question really ... but lately I've been working on some project all day long, and my eyes are hurting. How can one save settings (color settings to be exact) in matlab, so one can reload them / interchange them for different ones when day goes and night comes ?

A subquestion - where exactly does matlab (2008b in this case, I think) saves its settings ? Can they be backuped ?

Comment: methinks http://superuser.com/ would be of more assistance to your quandry

Comment: @Mechko - 6 matlab questions there vs. 709 here ? Why do you think I would get more assistance there ?

Comment: Well... this is not exactly a programming question, is it?

Comment: Neither are half of the ones under vim, emacs, visual stduio, or many others. But those are tools used by programmers and have always been welcomed here. Listen, I'm tired and not really in the mood for repeating this argument one more time. If you really wish to move it that much, move it ... but then please, answer it as well! Don't move it just for the sake of moving it. Be useful while you're at it.

Comment: Hey man take care of your eyes.

Comment: if you get no real answers try firing up ProcMon (google) - best tool ever for answering questions like this.

Comment: Depending on your other settings, changing the screen resolution, font family, or font size may help with the eye strain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings are stored in the preferences directory. For a particular user per install you can find where it is using the `prefdir` command at the Command Prompt. I wrote a bit about it on our official blog, if you'd like more information. http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2009/12/07/the-preferences-directory/

Comment: That looks pretty much what I was looking for. Off to experiment :) Thanks Mike !

Answer (score 8):

Preferences are stored in user-readable text files in the prefdir folder. Each of the line entries in this file corresponds to a single preference. These entries are explained here: 
http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/changing-system-preferences-programmatically/

Per your request, you can have two versions of the relevant preferences file, and programmatically (or manually) switch them (don't forget to restart Matlab after changing the preferences.)