# In a script, how to known if Matlab is running in Interactive (trough emacs) or in Batch?

Tags: matlab, emacs

In my Matlab script I would like to discriminate the case where the script is run in Interactive trough emacs matlab mode or in Batch.

By running in Batch I mean running as explained on Matlab website here http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15HNG.

For example trough a variable for doing think like this:

```
if (SCRIPT_RUNNING_IN_BATCH==1)
  do_this;
end
```

Is there a way to doing this?

Comment: by *Batch*, did you mean running as `matlab -r scrName`? Can you clarify?

Comment: By Batch I mean running as: unset DISPLAY && matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -timing < srcName.m. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following:

```
function retval = isCommandWindowOpen()
    jDesktop = com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance;
    retval = ~isempty(jDesktop.getClient('Command Window'));
end
```

<sub>as mentioned earlier, this is a copy from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10817833/1162609)</sub>

Comment: Thanks. It's working with the regular Matlab interface. I known I abuse but I use Matlab trought emacs. In the emacs matlab mode it's always return 0.

Comment: after re-reading your question, I think this is not the ideal solution. This is just for detecting the difference between default behaviour and `-nodesktop`; these are both interactive I guess.. imo you're better of converting the script to a function and going with @Memming's answer

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an argument when running MATLAB without interaction mode. For example, you can pass 15 to your function named `srcName` via:

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -timing -r srcName(15)
```

This won't work for a script though.

I'm a ViM user, and slimux works perfectly. I'm sure you can setup your fancy emacs to do a similar interaction with an interactive MATLAB instead of calling MATLAB every time.