# How can I programatically differentiate between an interactive and batch process?

Tags: matlab

I have some scripts that I would like to run in the background on my desktop (Windows 7) machine. I understand that to do that I need to start MATLAB with a command like:

`matlab -nosplash -noFigureWindows -r "myScriptName"`

I also understand that for this to work cleanly, I need to include an `exit` command at the end of my script.

Is there a way to robustly determine whether the script is being run in a background process or interactively? I would like to avoid the situation where I inadvertently run a script during an interactive process and accidentally kill my MATLAB session.

```
if ~RunningInInteractiveMode
    exit
end
```

Is there a function or other boolean test I can substitute for `~RunningInInteractiveMode`? I looked at [these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547755/in-a-script-how-to-known-if-matlab-is-running-in-interactive-trough-emacs-or), but Windows does not have a `-noDesktop` option, so there is always a command window open (auxiliary question: can one run MATLAB in windows completely in the background without the full command window opening?). If it matters, I am running r2014a.

Comment: @BryanP: Please don't add tags to the title. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/376604 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could run the script with an argument:

```
matlab -nosplash -noFigureWindows -r "background=true;myscript"
```

That way at the end of the script:

```
if exist background
    exit
end
```

Comment: That's close, but if I then run the script in interactive mode, it will throw an error because the variable `background` will be undefined. I suppose that's not a big deal because these would be the three final lines of the script, so all the important code will have run and my variables will be appropriately populated. It seems like MATLAB should have some situational awareness of its surroundings, though.

Comment: `if exist background`

Answer (score 1):

Use `feature('ShowFigureWindows')` to check if `-noFigureWindows` is used and `usejava('jvm')` to detect if JRE is available.

```
background_task=~feature('ShowFigureWindows')||~usejava('jvm')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `exit` to your script, you can add it to your command line:

```
matlab -nosplash -noFigureWindows -r "myScriptName;exit"
```